# Update: Removing the Outermost pair of bracket from a List

Tags: list-manipulation

Let

```
m1={{1,0},{0,1}};
m2={{2,0},{0,1}};
```

I want to evaluate `KroneckerProduct[m1, m1, m2]`, and I want to do this as `KroneckerProduct[Table[m1, {i, 1, 2}], m2]` I want to use `Table`, because number of `m1` are more than two in general.

but `Table[m1, {i, 1, 2}]` generates

```
{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}
```

and  presence of Extra curly bracket `{}` does not work in `KroneckerProduct`. I want to remove it.

**Some help has been below but that makes it string, which does not solve the problem**

Pl help.

Comment: @andre314 Thanks for help.

Comment: `StringRiffle[{"1", "2"}, ","]`

Comment: @andre314 Yes, understood, thanks

Comment: @andre314 I have updated ques, See if you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So two things,

1. you don't actually need to use `Table` because you're just duplicating something over and over, so we can use [`ConstantArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html) to be more efficient and not "create" iterators, and
2. I think the easiest way to "get rid of the outermost brackets" is to [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) the [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) head to the list via `## & @@ list`.

So you could implement this either directly in the final computation as

```
KroneckerProduct[## & @@ ConstantArray[m1, 2], m2]
```

or

```
KroneckerProduct[##, m2] & @@ ConstantArray[m1, 2]
```

Both of these methods give

> {{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 1}}

These methods can be generalized to output the results for different amounts of `m1`s in the product.  Something else to think about is, since the Kronecker Product is associative/flat (i.e. $(a \otimes b) \otimes c = a \otimes (b \otimes c)$), you could first calculate the product of all the `m1`s by themselves to possibly get a closed form, then have $\left( \bigotimes\limits^N m_1 \right) \otimes m_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved

Comment: I hope you have understood why it solved your problem. Please see the documentation for `Apply`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
Range@5 // StringRiffle[#, ","] &
```

> "1,2,3,4,5"

---

F1 has this:

[image]

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html